# How can I get keybert on python 3.10?

Tags: python, python-3.10

```
sjm@SJMui-MacBookAir workspace % pip3 install keybert
Collecting keybert
  Using cached keybert-0.5.1.tar.gz (19 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting sentence-transformers>=0.3.8
  Using cached sentence-transformers-2.2.0.tar.gz (79 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting scikit-learn>=0.22.2
  Using cached scikit_learn-1.0.2-cp310-cp310-macosx_10_13_x86_64.whl (8.0 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.18.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from keybert) (1.22.3)
Collecting rich>=10.4.0
  Using cached rich-12.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (229 kB)
Collecting commonmark<0.10.0,>=0.9.0
  Using cached commonmark-0.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (51 kB)
Collecting pygments<3.0.0,>=2.6.0
  Using cached Pygments-2.11.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
Collecting threadpoolctl>=2.0.0
  Using cached threadpoolctl-3.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting joblib>=0.11
  Using cached joblib-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (306 kB)
Collecting scipy>=1.1.0
  Using cached scipy-1.8.0-cp310-cp310-macosx_12_0_universal2.macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (55.6 MB)
Collecting transformers<5.0.0,>=4.6.0
  Using cached transformers-4.18.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.0 MB)
Collecting tqdm
  Using cached tqdm-4.64.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: torch>=1.6.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from sentence-transformers>=0.3.8->keybert) (1.11.0)
Collecting torchvision
  Using cached torchvision-0.12.0-cp310-cp310-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (1.3 MB)
Collecting nltk
  Using cached nltk-3.7-py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
Collecting sentencepiece
  Using cached sentencepiece-0.1.96.tar.gz (508 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting huggingface-hub
  Using cached huggingface_hub-0.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from torch>=1.6.0->sentence-transformers>=0.3.8->keybert) (4.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from transformers<5.0.0,>=4.6.0->sentence-transformers>=0.3.8->keybert) (2.27.1)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from transformers<5.0.0,>=4.6.0->sentence-transformers>=0.3.8->keybert) (21.3)
Collecting filelock
  Using cached filelock-3.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (10.0 kB)
Collecting sacremoses
  Using cached sacremoses-0.0.49-py3-none-any.whl (895 kB)
Collecting regex!=2019.12.17
  Using cached regex-2022.3.15-cp310-cp310-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (288 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: tokenizers!=0.11.3,<0.13,>=0.11.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from transformers<5.0.0,>=4.6.0->sentence-transformers>=0.3.8->keybert) (0.11.6)
Collecting pyyaml>=5.1
  Using cached PyYAML-6.0-cp310-cp310-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (197 kB)
Collecting click
  Using cached click-8.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow!=8.3.*,>=5.3.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from torchvision->sentence-transformers>=0.3.8->keybert) (9.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=3.0.5,>=2.0.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from packaging>=20.0->transformers<5.0.0,>=4.6.0->sentence-transformers>=0.3.8->keybert) (3.0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests->transformers<5.0.0,>=4.6.0->sentence-transformers>=0.3.8->keybert) (1.26.9)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests->transformers<5.0.0,>=4.6.0->sentence-transformers>=0.3.8->keybert) (2021.10.8)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests->transformers<5.0.0,>=4.6.0->sentence-transformers>=0.3.8->keybert) (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests->transformers<5.0.0,>=4.6.0->sentence-transformers>=0.3.8->keybert) (2.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from sacremoses->transformers<5.0.0,>=4.6.0->sentence-transformers>=0.3.8->keybert) (1.16.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: keybert, sentence-transformers, sentencepiece
  Building wheel for keybert (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for keybert: filename=keybert-0.5.1-py3-none-any.whl size=21332 sha256=2e529e77832edd062d95469f0930ebd558140cd8f14f865fcb0253b2282b9398
  Stored in directory: /Users/sjm/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/60/11/e8/2c3d18d1ecd66319071710eb076396a107fd64abf391fc2373
  Building wheel for sentence-transformers (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for sentence-transformers: filename=sentence_transformers-2.2.0-py3-none-any.whl size=120747 sha256=5d73ab7dc222c52b59af31b2e4773f445253df5b4f111575621d6e0d030d50eb
  Stored in directory: /Users/sjm/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/54/0d/ea/b89527acdff464eb4476a68607f6ca4e8ad24b6f6d5e8cfacb
  Building wheel for sentencepiece (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [162 lines of output]
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:717: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead
        warnings.warn(
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/sentencepiece
      copying src/sentencepiece/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/sentencepiece
      copying src/sentencepiece/sentencepiece_model_pb2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/sentencepiece
      copying src/sentencepiece/sentencepiece_pb2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/sentencepiece
      running build_ext
      /bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
      'sentencepiece'에 복제합니다...
      Note: switching to 'd8711f55d9b2cb9c77a00adcc18108482b29b675'.
      
      You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
      changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
      state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.
      
      If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
      do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:
      
        git switch -c <new-branch-name>
      
      Or undo this operation with:
      
        git switch -
      
      Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false
      
      -- VERSION: 0.1.96
      -- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.5.12050022
      -- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.5.12050022
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc - skipped
      -- Detecting C compile features
      -- Detecting C compile features - done
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
      -- Detecting CXX compile features
      -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
      -- Looking for pthread.h
      -- Looking for pthread.h - found
      -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
      -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
      -- Found Threads: TRUE
      -- Not Found TCMalloc: TCMALLOC_LIB-NOTFOUND
      -- Configuring done
      -- Generating done
      -- Build files have been written to: /private/var/folders/8k/xtp1m_gj32j_4csc8gt_qkwh0000gn/T/pip-install-bmkrwbw5/sentencepiece_64ef20310355401d9b58fc2dc5c01f8b/bundled/sentencepiece/build
      ./build_bundled.sh: line 16: nproc: command not found
      [  3%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece_train-static.dir/unicode_script.cc.o
      [  3%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece_train-static.dir/builder.cc.o
      [  4%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece_train-static.dir/trainer_factory.cc.o
      [  6%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece_train-static.dir/trainer_interface.cc.o
      [  7%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/__/third_party/protobuf-lite/arena.cc.o
      [ 11%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/__/third_party/protobuf-lite/arenastring.cc.o
      [ 12%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece_train-static.dir/word_model_trainer.cc.o
      [  9%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece_train-static.dir/unigram_model_trainer.cc.o
      [ 14%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/__/third_party/protobuf-lite/bytestream.cc.o
      [ 15%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/__/third_party/protobuf-lite/coded_stream.cc.o
      [ 19%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece_train-static.dir/bpe_model_trainer.cc.o
      [ 17%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece_train-static.dir/char_model_trainer.cc.o
      [ 20%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/__/third_party/protobuf-lite/extension_set.cc.o
      [ 23%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/__/third_party/protobuf-lite/common.cc.o
      [ 23%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece_train-static.dir/sentencepiece_trainer.cc.o
      [ 25%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/__/third_party/protobuf-lite/generated_enum_util.cc.o
      [ 26%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/__/third_party/protobuf-lite/generated_message_table_driven_lite.cc.o
      [ 28%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece_train-static.dir/pretokenizer_for_training.cc.o
      [ 30%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/__/third_party/protobuf-lite/generated_message_util.cc.o
      [ 31%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/__/third_party/protobuf-lite/implicit_weak_message.cc.o
      [ 33%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/__/third_party/protobuf-lite/message_lite.cc.o
      [ 34%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/__/third_party/protobuf-lite/parse_context.cc.o
      [ 36%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/__/third_party/protobuf-lite/io_win32.cc.o
      [ 38%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/__/third_party/protobuf-lite/int128.cc.o
      [ 39%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/__/third_party/protobuf-lite/repeated_field.cc.o
      [ 41%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/__/third_party/protobuf-lite/status.cc.o
      [ 42%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/__/third_party/protobuf-lite/statusor.cc.o
      [ 44%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/__/third_party/protobuf-lite/stringpiece.cc.o
      [ 46%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/__/third_party/protobuf-lite/stringprintf.cc.o
      [ 47%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/__/third_party/protobuf-lite/strutil.cc.o
      [ 49%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/__/third_party/protobuf-lite/structurally_valid.cc.o
      [ 50%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/__/third_party/protobuf-lite/wire_format_lite.cc.o
      [ 53%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/__/third_party/protobuf-lite/zero_copy_stream.cc.o
      [ 53%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/__/third_party/protobuf-lite/time.cc.o
      [ 55%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/__/third_party/protobuf-lite/zero_copy_stream_impl.cc.o
      [ 57%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/__/third_party/protobuf-lite/zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.cc.o
      [ 58%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/builtin_pb/sentencepiece.pb.cc.o
      [ 60%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/builtin_pb/sentencepiece_model.pb.cc.o
      [ 61%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/bpe_model.cc.o
      [ 63%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/char_model.cc.o
      [ 65%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/error.cc.o
      [ 66%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/filesystem.cc.o
      [ 69%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/model_interface.cc.o
      [ 69%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/normalizer.cc.o
      [ 71%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/model_factory.cc.o
      [ 73%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/sentencepiece_processor.cc.o
      [ 74%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/unigram_model.cc.o
      [ 76%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/util.cc.o
      [ 77%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/word_model.cc.o
      [ 79%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/__/third_party/absl/strings/string_view.cc.o
      [ 80%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/sentencepiece-static.dir/__/third_party/absl/flags/flag.cc.o
      /private/var/folders/8k/xtp1m_gj32j_4csc8gt_qkwh0000gn/T/pip-install-bmkrwbw5/sentencepiece_64ef20310355401d9b58fc2dc5c01f8b/bundled/sentencepiece/src/builder.cc:46:15: warning: unused variable 'kMaxUnicode' [-Wunused-const-variable]
      constexpr int kMaxUnicode = 0x10FFFF;
                    ^
      /private/var/folders/8k/xtp1m_gj32j_4csc8gt_qkwh0000gn/T/pip-install-bmkrwbw5/sentencepiece_64ef20310355401d9b58fc2dc5c01f8b/bundled/sentencepiece/src/builder.cc:48:23: warning: unused variable 'kDefaultNormalizerName' [-Wunused-const-variable]
      static constexpr char kDefaultNormalizerName[] = "nfkc";
                            ^
      2 warnings generated.
      [ 82%] Linking CXX static library libsentencepiece.a
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libsentencepiece.a(io_win32.cc.o) has no symbols
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libsentencepiece.a(io_win32.cc.o) has no symbols
      [ 82%] Built target sentencepiece-static
      [ 84%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/spm_decode.dir/spm_decode_main.cc.o
      [ 85%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/spm_encode.dir/spm_encode_main.cc.o
      [ 87%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/spm_export_vocab.dir/spm_export_vocab_main.cc.o
      [ 88%] Linking CXX executable spm_export_vocab
      [ 88%] Built target spm_export_vocab
      [ 90%] Linking CXX executable spm_decode
      [ 92%] Linking CXX static library libsentencepiece_train.a
      [ 92%] Built target spm_decode
      [ 92%] Built target sentencepiece_train-static
      [ 93%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/spm_train.dir/spm_train_main.cc.o
      [ 95%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/spm_normalize.dir/spm_normalize_main.cc.o
      [ 96%] Linking CXX executable spm_encode
      [ 96%] Built target spm_encode
      [ 98%] Linking CXX executable spm_normalize
      [100%] Linking CXX executable spm_train
      [100%] Built target spm_normalize
      [100%] Built target spm_train
      Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target sentencepiece-static
      [ 66%] Built target sentencepiece-static
      Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target sentencepiece_train-static
      [ 84%] Built target sentencepiece_train-static
      Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target spm_encode
      [ 87%] Built target spm_encode
      Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target spm_decode
      [ 90%] Built target spm_decode
      Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target spm_normalize
      [ 93%] Built target spm_normalize
      Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target spm_train
      [ 96%] Built target spm_train
      Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target spm_export_vocab
      [100%] Built target spm_export_vocab
      Install the project...
      -- Install configuration: ""
      -- Installing: /private/var/folders/8k/xtp1m_gj32j_4csc8gt_qkwh0000gn/T/pip-install-bmkrwbw5/sentencepiece_64ef20310355401d9b58fc2dc5c01f8b/bundled/lib/pkgconfig/sentencepiece.pc
      -- Installing: /private/var/folders/8k/xtp1m_gj32j_4csc8gt_qkwh0000gn/T/pip-install-bmkrwbw5/sentencepiece_64ef20310355401d9b58fc2dc5c01f8b/bundled/lib/libsentencepiece.a
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: file: /private/var/folders/8k/xtp1m_gj32j_4csc8gt_qkwh0000gn/T/pip-install-bmkrwbw5/sentencepiece_64ef20310355401d9b58fc2dc5c01f8b/bundled/lib/libsentencepiece.a(io_win32.cc.o) has no symbols
      -- Installing: /private/var/folders/8k/xtp1m_gj32j_4csc8gt_qkwh0000gn/T/pip-install-bmkrwbw5/sentencepiece_64ef20310355401d9b58fc2dc5c01f8b/bundled/lib/libsentencepiece_train.a
      -- Installing: /private/var/folders/8k/xtp1m_gj32j_4csc8gt_qkwh0000gn/T/pip-install-bmkrwbw5/sentencepiece_64ef20310355401d9b58fc2dc5c01f8b/bundled/bin/spm_encode
      -- Installing: /private/var/folders/8k/xtp1m_gj32j_4csc8gt_qkwh0000gn/T/pip-install-bmkrwbw5/sentencepiece_64ef20310355401d9b58fc2dc5c01f8b/bundled/bin/spm_decode
      -- Installing: /private/var/folders/8k/xtp1m_gj32j_4csc8gt_qkwh0000gn/T/pip-install-bmkrwbw5/sentencepiece_64ef20310355401d9b58fc2dc5c01f8b/bundled/bin/spm_normalize
      -- Installing: /private/var/folders/8k/xtp1m_gj32j_4csc8gt_qkwh0000gn/T/pip-install-bmkrwbw5/sentencepiece_64ef20310355401d9b58fc2dc5c01f8b/bundled/bin/spm_train
      -- Installing: /private/var/folders/8k/xtp1m_gj32j_4csc8gt_qkwh0000gn/T/pip-install-bmkrwbw5/sentencepiece_64ef20310355401d9b58fc2dc5c01f8b/bundled/bin/spm_export_vocab
      -- Installing: /private/var/folders/8k/xtp1m_gj32j_4csc8gt_qkwh0000gn/T/pip-install-bmkrwbw5/sentencepiece_64ef20310355401d9b58fc2dc5c01f8b/bundled/include/sentencepiece_trainer.h
      -- Installing: /private/var/folders/8k/xtp1m_gj32j_4csc8gt_qkwh0000gn/T/pip-install-bmkrwbw5/sentencepiece_64ef20310355401d9b58fc2dc5c01f8b/bundled/include/sentencepiece_processor.h
      env: pkg-config: No such file or directory
      Failed to find sentencepiece pkg-config
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for sentencepiece
  Running setup.py clean for sentencepiece
Successfully built keybert sentence-transformers
Failed to build sentencepiece
Installing collected packages: sentencepiece, commonmark, tqdm, threadpoolctl, scipy, regex, pyyaml, pygments, joblib, filelock, click, torchvision, scikit-learn, sacremoses, rich, nltk, huggingface-hub, transformers, sentence-transformers, keybert
  Running setup.py install for sentencepiece ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for sentencepiece did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [60 lines of output]
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:717: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead
        warnings.warn(
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/sentencepiece
      copying src/sentencepiece/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/sentencepiece
      copying src/sentencepiece/sentencepiece_model_pb2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/sentencepiece
      copying src/sentencepiece/sentencepiece_pb2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/sentencepiece
      running build_ext
      /bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
      mkdir: bundled: File exists
      fatal: 대상 경로가('sentencepiece') 이미 있고 빈 디렉터리가 아닙니다.
      fatal: 대상 경로가('sentencepiece') 이미 있고 빈 디렉터리가 아닙니다.
      mkdir: build: File exists
      -- VERSION: 0.1.96
      -- Not Found TCMalloc: TCMALLOC_LIB-NOTFOUND
      -- Configuring done
      -- Generating done
      -- Build files have been written to: /private/var/folders/8k/xtp1m_gj32j_4csc8gt_qkwh0000gn/T/pip-install-bmkrwbw5/sentencepiece_64ef20310355401d9b58fc2dc5c01f8b/bundled/sentencepiece/build
      ./build_bundled.sh: line 16: nproc: command not found
      Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target sentencepiece_train-static
      [ 17%] Built target sentencepiece_train-static
      Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target sentencepiece-static
      [ 84%] Built target sentencepiece-static
      Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target spm_train
      Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target spm_normalize
      Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target spm_decode
      Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target spm_encode
      Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target spm_export_vocab
      [ 87%] Built target spm_train
      [ 90%] Built target spm_decode
      [ 93%] Built target spm_encode
      [ 96%] Built target spm_normalize
      [100%] Built target spm_export_vocab
      [ 66%] Built target sentencepiece-static
      [ 84%] Built target sentencepiece_train-static
      [ 87%] Built target spm_encode
      [ 90%] Built target spm_decode
      [ 93%] Built target spm_normalize
      [ 96%] Built target spm_train
      [100%] Built target spm_export_vocab
      Install the project...
      -- Install configuration: ""
      -- Up-to-date: /private/var/folders/8k/xtp1m_gj32j_4csc8gt_qkwh0000gn/T/pip-install-bmkrwbw5/sentencepiece_64ef20310355401d9b58fc2dc5c01f8b/bundled/lib/pkgconfig/sentencepiece.pc
      -- Installing: /private/var/folders/8k/xtp1m_gj32j_4csc8gt_qkwh0000gn/T/pip-install-bmkrwbw5/sentencepiece_64ef20310355401d9b58fc2dc5c01f8b/bundled/lib/libsentencepiece.a
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: file: /private/var/folders/8k/xtp1m_gj32j_4csc8gt_qkwh0000gn/T/pip-install-bmkrwbw5/sentencepiece_64ef20310355401d9b58fc2dc5c01f8b/bundled/lib/libsentencepiece.a(io_win32.cc.o) has no symbols
      -- Installing: /private/var/folders/8k/xtp1m_gj32j_4csc8gt_qkwh0000gn/T/pip-install-bmkrwbw5/sentencepiece_64ef20310355401d9b58fc2dc5c01f8b/bundled/lib/libsentencepiece_train.a
      -- Installing: /private/var/folders/8k/xtp1m_gj32j_4csc8gt_qkwh0000gn/T/pip-install-bmkrwbw5/sentencepiece_64ef20310355401d9b58fc2dc5c01f8b/bundled/bin/spm_encode
      -- Installing: /private/var/folders/8k/xtp1m_gj32j_4csc8gt_qkwh0000gn/T/pip-install-bmkrwbw5/sentencepiece_64ef20310355401d9b58fc2dc5c01f8b/bundled/bin/spm_decode
      -- Installing: /private/var/folders/8k/xtp1m_gj32j_4csc8gt_qkwh0000gn/T/pip-install-bmkrwbw5/sentencepiece_64ef20310355401d9b58fc2dc5c01f8b/bundled/bin/spm_normalize
      -- Up-to-date: /private/var/folders/8k/xtp1m_gj32j_4csc8gt_qkwh0000gn/T/pip-install-bmkrwbw5/sentencepiece_64ef20310355401d9b58fc2dc5c01f8b/bundled/bin/spm_train
      error: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/install_name_tool: for: /private/var/folders/8k/xtp1m_gj32j_4csc8gt_qkwh0000gn/T/pip-install-bmkrwbw5/sentencepiece_64ef20310355401d9b58fc2dc5c01f8b/bundled/bin/spm_train (for architecture x86_64) option "-add_rpath /private/var/folders/8k/xtp1m_gj32j_4csc8gt_qkwh0000gn/T/pip-install-bmkrwbw5/sentencepiece_64ef20310355401d9b58fc2dc5c01f8b/bundled/lib" would duplicate path, file already has LC_RPATH for: /private/var/folders/8k/xtp1m_gj32j_4csc8gt_qkwh0000gn/T/pip-install-bmkrwbw5/sentencepiece_64ef20310355401d9b58fc2dc5c01f8b/bundled/lib
      -- Installing: /private/var/folders/8k/xtp1m_gj32j_4csc8gt_qkwh0000gn/T/pip-install-bmkrwbw5/sentencepiece_64ef20310355401d9b58fc2dc5c01f8b/bundled/bin/spm_export_vocab
      -- Up-to-date: /private/var/folders/8k/xtp1m_gj32j_4csc8gt_qkwh0000gn/T/pip-install-bmkrwbw5/sentencepiece_64ef20310355401d9b58fc2dc5c01f8b/bundled/include/sentencepiece_trainer.h
      -- Up-to-date: /private/var/folders/8k/xtp1m_gj32j_4csc8gt_qkwh0000gn/T/pip-install-bmkrwbw5/sentencepiece_64ef20310355401d9b58fc2dc5c01f8b/bundled/include/sentencepiece_processor.h
      env: pkg-config: No such file or directory
      Failed to find sentencepiece pkg-config
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> sentencepiece

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I just want to install keybert and It doens't work.

I tried to install

- "sentencepiece"
- "setup.py"
- "wheel"
- "Cmake"

in manual command but only "wheel", "Cmake" were succeed

My system is

- Mac OS
- VSC
- Python 3.10.4 64-bit
- terminal in vsc

I'm wondering, Doesn't keybert support python 3.10?
In that case, Should I downgrade interperter?